# Rails Single Class with 40 fields or 6 Classes with single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, oop, activerecord

I am making a classifieds website in rails 4.1 and am wondering which would perform better for searching given tens or hundreds of thousands of records; one class with 50 fields or multiple smaller classes with inheritance. A typical Object Oriented approach would certainly work here and I would lay it out like this.

The base class would be **`Posts`** and would have fields like: `Price` `City` `Description` `User` `Category` `Condition` `Buying or Selling` `Flagged Inappropriate` `Sold`, etc.

The child classes would be things like:

**`Automobiles:`** with fields like `Year` `Make` `Model` `Color` `Transmission` `Drive Type` etc
**`Housing:`** with fields like: `Number of rooms` `Housing Type` `Private / Shared` `Floor #` etc
**`Computers:`** with things like: `Notebook/Desktop` `RAM` `HDD size` `Screen Size` etc

And you could imagine other fields for things like:
**`Clothes:`**
**`Jobs:`**
**`Phones:`**

So as I said earlier typically I would approach this from an object oriented perspective but from a performance perspective, would a single table be faster? **Note:** The user will be both searching through all types of posts and also through specific categories of posts. So on the homepage a user might search for "2004 Toyota 4runner" without specifying a category but they might also click on Automobiles and then type in their search.

*Also in case you are wondering why I am making such a project, I live in an undeveloped country where nothing good like this exists :)*

Thanks,

Comment: You always have to accept a degree of fuzziness in your modelling for this sort of thing. Otherwise, what if the computer has 2 HDDs of different types? Etc. Worth thinking about how precise you want to be.